# call member function of a vector of templated class

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I have a templated class (BTW, I use a templated class because it gives huge performance gain):

`template<int n>
class A;`

My first issue was that I wanted to make a vector of it. Some people suggest using `boost::any`, for now I just use `void*`.

`A<1> a0;
A<2> a1;
vector<void*> v;
v.push_back(&a0);
v.push_back(&a1);`

The problem comes when I want to call some member function of the element of this vector:

`for(auto a : v)
  (A*)a->foo();`

Of course, this does not work, because I don't provide the template argument during the converstion....
But, I don't find any good way to make this works.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Please post some real code. `A<1> a0();` is a function declaration.

Comment: This is real code. `A<1> a0();` calls the constructor. Remove your downvote.

Comment: No. It's a function declaration. See *most vexing parse*.

Comment: `A<1> a0;` or `A<1> a0{};` call the constructor, `A<1> a0();` is a function declaration.

Comment: Ok, you are right. But, when did stack overflow became so mean? According to wikipedia this is a super subtle mistake. I just posted a simplified version of my actual code, which had constructor arguments.

Comment: @Oli I have no clue why you have so many downvotes. People who post code dumps and scream "THIS DOESNT WORK FIX IT PLZ KTHXBAI" sometimes get higher scores than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`A<1>` and `A<2>` are *completely separate classes*.

Consider: if you have two classes X and Y that both have a `foo` method:

```
class X {public: void foo() {std::cout << "X::foo" << std::endl;}};
class Y {public: void foo() {std::cout << "Y::foo" << std::endl;}};
```

and a vector of `void*`'s, then how can you call the `foo` method on all of them?

```
vector<void*> v;
v.push_back(new X);
v.push_back(new Y);
for(auto a : v)
    a->foo(); // how can I do this?
```

The answer is simple: **you can't** access a member by name like this.

(What if someone made a class `Z` that also had a `foo` method? Then you'd expect this to call it if there was a `Z` in the vector; but member names are removed when the code is compiled, so it wouldn't know that this member was also called `foo`!)

However, you could create a base class and make the method virtual:

```
class XYBase {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}
class X : public XYBase {public: void foo() {std::cout << "X::foo" << std::endl;}};
class Y : public XYBase {public: void foo() {std::cout << "Y::foo" << std::endl;}};
```

and then you can have a `vector<XYBase*>`:

```
vector<XYBase*> v;
v.push_back(new X);
v.push_back(new Y);
for(auto a : v)
    a->foo(); // works!
```

The template equivalent would be:

```
class XBase {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
}

template<int N> class X : public XBase {
public:
    void foo() {
        std::cout << "X<" << N << ">::foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

// ... later ...

vector<XBase*> v;
v.push_back(new X<1>);
v.push_back(new X<2>);
for(auto a : v)
    a->foo(); // works!
```

Comment: @Oli: If this is the main use of your class, you probably want to check your performance again. Introducing a base class in order to access your class(es) in a polymorphic way might eat up any performance gain you got by templating that class in the first place.